# How can I get the first non-white space character of a line using php

Tags: php, whitespace

I have a line that typically starts with a few spaces as the lines are in columns and use a monospace font to make things line up.  I want to check if the first non-white space character (or even just the first thing that isn't a space) and see if that is a number.  What is the least server intensive way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `trim()` (or `ltrim()` in this case) to delete the whitespace, and make use of the array access of strings:

```
$line = ltrim($line);
is_numeric($line[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression:

```
if (preg_match('/^\s*(\S)/m', $line, $match)) {
    var_dump($match[0]);
}
```

Or you remove any whitespace at the begin and then get the first character:

```
$line_clean = ltrim($line);
var_dump(substr($line_clean, 0, 1));
```

Comment: It would be nice to get a comment on why my answer got voted down.

Comment: Talk about blatant "strategic downvoting". Sheesh.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (preg_match('/^\s*\d/', $line)) {
    // ^    starting at the beginning of the line
    // \s*  look for zero or more whitespace characters
    // \d   and then a digit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$first = substr(trim($string), 0, 1);
$is_num = is_numeric($first);
return $is_num;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try RegEx:

```
$Line = ...;
preg_match('/^[:space:]*(.)/', $Line, $matches);
$FirstChar = $matches[0];
```